# How to make a link not cover the whole page?

Tags: html, css

Okay so im a beginner at html and ive been making this website just for fun and i keep running into one problem. When i have a button it makes the entire place clickable so even if theres a bunch of empty space in the left and right you will still be able to click it on the left and right without actually hovering over the button. So does anyone have a suggestion for how to fix this? I'll put the code below in an image tho because i cant seem to do it normally lol.

[I put the buttons in a div to easily make them vertical](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N36bj.png)

[And here is the css for it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1Z8n.png)

I thought it might have been because the buttons are in a div but i tried removing the div and making them seperate but it still happens.

Comment: Welcome! You need to post your code here (yes CSS is code too). Linked screenshots aren't enough.

Comment: @Hexodus I posted all my css code and i cant seem to post my html code in pure text because then it gets completely well fucky wucky basically. Idrk how i should be able to post it

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: Well just click on @Paulie_D link to Stack Snippet and follow the instructions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would like to suggest **not to use margin property to position the div**, it will only lead to the div taking a lot more space than it is supposed to, which is the reason why the entire body is clickable.

**Solution** - Use css position property for positioning the elements.
Here we are absolute positioning div container instead of using the margins.
You can find info here on how to use the property:
https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/position/

```css
body {
  text-align: center
}
h1 {
  font-size: 24px;
}
.btn-group button{
  border: none;
  padding: 15px 10px;
  margin: 15%;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer
}
.btn-group {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-group">
  <a href="https://codepen.io/"><button type="button" name="button">Redd Cross</button></a>
  <a href="https://codepen.io/"><button type="button" name="button">Blue Cross</button></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank u very much been trying to understand how to use position lol

Comment: Well, the position: absolute property positions an element by taking the parent container's dimensions and position as reference.
So, top: 50% means push it down about half-way from the top of the parent and similarly left: 50% means push it halfway towards the left.